# MsgBox is coming below the Splash screen in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, splash-screen

I have a splash screen set using the Application Framework. In my main form, I check for some conditions in Load() event of the MainForm and display a MsgBox if some of them fails.

But the problem is, the MsgBox comes below the Splash Screen. Is there any way to correct this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this link: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/TopMostMessageBox.aspx

It's in C# but it could be converted easily using a conversion tool (I'd post a link to that but since I'm a new user it's only letting me post 1 link..)

Answer (score 3):

Show the MsgBox in the splash form's `Shown` event.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add a line in Message box style setting.

```
msgbox("Hello", MsgBoxStyle.MsgBoxSetForeground)
```

And if your are already using some other style setting such as MsgboxStyle.YesNo then simply add 'Or' in between two settings like.

```
msgbox("Hello", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo Or MsgBoxStyle.MsgBoxSetForeground)
```

This one worked fine for me